# Printing specific character that causes exception error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

So i am working on a assignment and I got everything worked out but the last part of the assignment is printing out the specific character that caused a execption error from user input through try-catch. Like example, I input "Greg Oxley", the catch should be getting the " " printed out as the cause of the error.

I tried using exception.getslacktrace, exception.getcause(), exception.getMessage(). still end up with no specific character.

```java
System.out.print("Enter a single word (letters only, please): ");
        String word = scan.nextLine();
//convert to all upper case
        word = word.toUpperCase();
//count frequency of each letter in string
// Put the body of the first for loop in a try.
// Add a catch that catches the exception, but don’t do anything with it.
//Compile and run your program.
        try{
            for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)
                counts[word.charAt(i)-'A']++;
        }
        catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Not a Letter: " + Exception.getMessage());

        }
```

I should be getting a specific character that is causing a exception "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" and printing it out. but instead I am still getting the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" printing out along with this output from Exception.getMessage() - "Index -12 out of bounds for length 26"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `i` before the `try` statement to be able to reference it in the `catch` statement :

```
int i = 0;

try{
    for (; i < word.length(); i++)
        counts[word.charAt(i)-'A']++;
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Exception)
{
    System.out.println("Not a Letter: " + word.charAt(i));

}
```

If you want to go on counting after the exception throw, you can move the `try/catch` statements inside the loop and so no need to declare `i` separately since that is now accessible :

```
for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++){
    try{
       counts[word.charAt(i)-'A']++;
    }
     catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Exception){
         System.out.println("Not a Letter: " + word.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I wasnt sure if that was the right way to go. Thank you.